# Angular UI router dynamically inject URL to html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to build a simple app, which goes the following way:

I have 2 menu items in the navbar: home and contact.

The home should be a unique URL only once from the server, at initialisation, read from a QR code (i got this covered, that is no problem to me) and the contact should always be the same.

I got the contact done in the following way:

```
$stateProvider.state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'src/views/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })
```

The problem is with the home, which should keep the unique URL received by the server. How should i write the state for that one?

```
        .state('home', {
            url: '/:uid',
            templateUrl: 'src/views/home.html',
        })
```

Also, the home should keep it's unique url generated by the server after refresh and while navigating from contact to home.

In the HTML i would have something like

```
<a ui-sref="home({uid: --some dynamic uid?--})">Home</a>
```

this is the part which also requires help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the home state to

```
.state('home', {
    url: /{uid},
    templateUrl: 'src/views/home.html',
})
```

and you could grab the parameters by injecting `$stateParams` into the controller. `$stateParams.uid` would return the parameters and store that in local storage or cookies.

Check this link out

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

**UPDATE:**

for example, this is the sample controller that is attached to the home page

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($stateParams) {
    var id = $stateParams.uid; //this is how you retrieve the uid
});
```

by going to your home page e.g. http://www.example.com/abcd12345, the above `$stateParams.uid` would return **abcd12345**

Now to set the url. simply use `ui-sref` instead of `href` on the `<a>` tag. ui-router will automatically generate `href` for you.

e.g.

```
<a ui-sref="home({uid:'abcd12345'})">Home</a>
```

Comment: based on what you wrote i have the following:
$stateParams = {
   id: $scope.img.param
}

and then 

.state('home', {
  url: '/:id'
})

how do i call this in html?

Comment: $stateParams doesn't get assigned to in your code. It contains the parsed query parameters that can be accessed by injecting `$stateParams` into the controller or into a function with in the `resolve` object or into the `onEnter`, and `onExit` functions.

You  set it with a `ui-sref` like this `ui-sref="home({id: <your value>})"`

Comment: This much i figured out for myself, still I appreciate the effort into helping me. My problem is, that `<a ui-sref="home({uid:'abcd12345'})">Home</a> ` is a hardcoded value for abcd12345... what I would like is that value to be dynamic. If I hardcode my home to that uid, it will always have the same value. Is it possible to have someting like `<a ui-sref="home({uid:'{{some dynamic value here}}'})">Home</a>` ?

Comment: @LeviF. you can execute a function that grabs the UID from the controller

e.g. `<a ui-sref="home({uid: '{{ vm.getUID() }}' })">Home</a>`

where vm.getUID() is a method from your controller

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a custom provider and inject it into the config.
eg:- .config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,yourprovider) .
I am not sure about this. But please check this way too..